# MYSQL insert between two related table

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have three tables like so

**product** table -

| id | product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | product1 |
| 2 | product2 |

**inventory_1** table

| product_id | inventory |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |

**inventory_2** table

| product_id | inventory |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 |

both `product_id` references **product** tables `id`. Now how can i insert **inventory_2** tables `inventory` into **inventory_1** tables `inventory`.

Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want go *update* `inventory_1` with the information in `inventory_2`:

```
update inventory_1 i1 join
       inventory_2 i2
       using (product_id)
    set i1.inventory = i1.inventory + i2.inventory;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, can I ask where do you learn these from. I have extremely difficult time  trying to find these things from documentation. I don't know what it does until I use it and I won't use it until I don't know what it does. It's a chicken-egg problem. Any advice?

Comment: @githubcopilot . . . I am quite experienced in SQL and data analysis.